# Able to connect through CMD but not to Oracle SQL developer to Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

So I got connected to Oracle 11g in cmd as follows

[image: screen shot connection in cmd]

However, when I type the same username and password in Oracle SQL Developer, it does not work. And I have uname and pwd, what goes in the connection name?

[image: Oracle Sql Developer]

This what I got, when i entered a connection name and My uname and PWD
[Oracle SQL Developer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWNuk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just give any string in your connection name, that is used for identify different connection in `sql developer`.

Like,

```
Connection name : Connection_1
username : system
password : yourpass
```

If you want to create another connection to another database or another schema then you have to give another name and by login you can directly access that particular schema.

Hope it will help.

Comment: check your ORACLE_HOME path. I guess there are two oracle directories. check in which directory TNS file is present.

Comment: there is no ORACLE_HOME .can you tell me how to set it, or refer to link if already exist.

Comment: yeah, set ORACLE_HOME and give path your oracle directory.

Comment: Should it be something like this in cmd                                        set ORACLE_HOME=C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be that SQL Developer uses a different tnsnames.ora file. The file can be set under:

```
Tools>Preferences>Database>Advanced
```

[image]

Choose the correct tnsnames directory there.
Depending on your developer version, you might also want to set the Oracle Client folder.

After that in your connection dialog choose TNS instead of BASIC. And pick the tnsalias name from the list from the file.

[image]

Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue and after trying series of steps came to this conclusion.

1)Make sure to follow the blog to install the DB and check the validation steps too :
  https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/Windows_DB_Install_OBE/Installing_Oracle_Db12c_Windows.html

This blog makes sure that you are able to connect to SQL via CMD.

2) If you still face issue while connecting to SQL developer for the same configuration,check :  Advanced system settings-->Environment variables-->system variables--> PATH

Make sure you have entry for the DB here.
 [Environment variable for DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4MEN.jpg)

3) If above step is a success,check the tnsnames.ora and listener.ora files present in the location : dbhome_1\network\admin

These files should have a valid entry for the localhost and SID/service name.

Thanks,
Sandeep